# RTE validation not happening

Tags: orbeon

https://gist.github.com/773349

RTE field validation is not happening if I traverse from RTE to RTE. Please find the attached git.

Steps to reproduce
Case 1

1. Focus into RTE1, type Hello
2. Tab out to text input (Node Selector)
3. Validation works

Case 2

1. Focus into RTE1, type Hello
2. Tab out to RTE2
3. Validation doesn't work

I tried with nightly build and was able to reproduce the above error and case 1 is failing too. An other difference that I noticed is "**xxforms-value-change-with-focus-change**" event is not fired when moved from RTE to RTE.

Comment: Is this a bug? looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed as of 2011-01-24, and this fix will be included in the Orbeon Forms 3.9 release. Also see: [ [#315639](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315639&group_id=168&atid=350207) ] RTE: values are not sent to the server when the RTE looses the focus.

Comment: We are on 3.8 and it comes with YUI 2.6.0. Unfortunately these events are not available in 2.6.0.

Comment: Right, this might not be a solution if you'd like to just patch the build you are using now. But nightly build have been on YUI 2.8.1 for a while, those events are now available in YUI 2.8.1, so supporting this in nightly builds turn out to be quite easy.

Comment: This bug is now fixed, and I updated my response accordingly.